# How can I convert an FAA pilot's certificate to a Canadian one?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, canada

What do I have to do to obtain a Canadian pilot's license if I already have an FAA one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Transport Canada has all the information [here](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/managementservices-referencecentre-acs-400-401-001-478.htm) for each FAA license type (and type ratings); the necessary forms and contacts are [here](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/general-personnel-usconversion-1806.htm). These are the basic requirements for a private pilot, for example:

> **6.1 Conditions for Conversion - Private Pilot – Aeroplane.**
>
> (1) Must hold an FAA Private airman certificate with airplane category and
>   class rating(s).
>
> (1) **Age**: Must be at least 17 years of age.
>   (2)
>   **Medical fitness**: Must hold either a Category 1 or Category 3 TCCA
>   medical.
>   (3) **Knowledge**: Must pass the Conversion - Private Pilot
>   Licence – Aeroplane, (FAAPA) written examination on air laws and
>   communications. Must be able to read, write and communicate in English
>   or French.
>   (4) **Experience**: Must provide proof of a minimum of 45
>   hours pilot flight time.
>   (5) **Skill**: No additional practical flight
>   test is required.

Comment: "Read, write and communicate in French." That'll probably catch a lot of Americans out... :/

Comment: Is "*either* English or French" what is intended?

Comment: If they meant "English and French," that is what they would have written. I'm surprised at this, however: you could only get away with speaking French in Quebec, where ATC are bilingual. Seems to me English should be required for a national certification.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone came here like me looking for the ability to just rent in Canada once in a while, You can go [**here**](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/managementservices-referencecentre-acs-400-400-003-122.htm#s5-1) and fill out the form. Apparently it only takes 2 days and costs $45 to get the Foreign License Validation Certificate.

You have to actually go to a Transport Canada office, which is a huge inconvenience if you aren't in one of the few Canadian cities that has one, but when you do go it's pretty straight forward, and your license validation lasts for a year.